# How to create object-based form-data when there are multiple, equally named form-elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, key-value, form-data

I'm trying to write a `form_to_json` serialization function in vanilla JS in order to create valid JSON.

But I'm stuck on parsing multiple inputs, all featuring the same name.

Here is my current function, note the comment where I'm stuck.

```
// gather form elements and serialize inputs
function form_to_json(form_id) {
  console.log(`Getting form with ID ${form_id}`);
  let obj_form = document.getElementById(form_id);

  // Create an object
  var obj = {};

  // Loop through each field in the form
  Array.prototype.slice.call(obj_form.elements).forEach(function(field) {
    // Skip some fields we don't need
    if (!field.name || field.disabled || ['file', 'reset', 'submit', 'button'].indexOf(field.type) > -1) return;

    // Handle multi-select fields
    if (field.type === 'select-multiple') {
      // Create an array of selected values
      var options = [];

      // Loop through the options and add selected ones
      Array.prototype.slice.call(field.options).forEach(function(option) {
        if (!option.selected) return;
        options.push(option.value);
      });

      // If there are any selection options, add them to the object
      if (options.length) {
        obj[field.name] = options;
      }

      return;
    }

    // If it's a checkbox or radio button and it's not checked, skip it
    if (['checkbox', 'radio'].indexOf(field.type) > -1 && !field.checked) return;

    console.log(`${field.name}: ${field.value}`);

    // Add the value to the object
    if (field.name in obj) {
      // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
      obj[field.name].push(field.value);
    } else {
      obj[field.name] = field.value;
    }
  });

  // Return the object
  return obj;
}
```

Here is a screenshot showing a visual of how the inputs are created by the end user.

[image]

With my current function code, I'm obviously only getting the last set of values for each redundant field name.

The front end allows user to dynamically add "criteria" rows (basically a set of those 3 inputs all named identically between each row).

My attempt was to check if the key already existed in the object, and if so, /do something/ but I can't work out what that something is.

Comment: it's conventional to use a name like `field[]` for fields that can be duplicated. Form processors then create an array of values for these fields.

Comment: ... nitpicking, but nevertheless important ... the **`form_to_json`** function does not create JSON (which is a string-based data-format), but it **unifies form-data in a custom way**.

Comment: @Source Matters ... the OP might have a look at a later provided approach/solution, sitting on the `FormData` Web-API, which helps minimizing the OP's own implementation effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the fact that the OP actually does not want to create `JSON` (which is a string-based data-format), but wants to create **unified form-data in a custom way**, any solution in first place should have been based at the usage of the [`FormData` Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), a form-data's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) list and a single [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

A `FormData` instance provides access to all of a form's relevant control/element-values, actually already filtered in the way the OP is looking for, which only leaves the task of collecting the values of equally named field-names into arrays, thus reducing the entries array (key-value pairs) into an object based data-structure.

The entire code becomes shorter and better readable.

```js
function getUnifiedFormData(elmForm) {
  return [
    ...new FormData(elmForm).entries()
  ]
  .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {

    if (Object.hasOwn(result, key)) {
      if (Array.isArray(result[key])) {

        result[key].push(value);
      } else {
        result[key] = [result[key], value];
      }
    } else {
      result[key] = value;
    }
    return result;

  }, {});
}
document
  .forms['my-form']
  .addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const data = getUnifiedFormData(evt.currentTarget);

    console.clear();
    console.log({ data });
  });
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 29%; }
label { float: left; margin: 2px 4px; }
select { clear: left; margin: 2px 0; padding: 2px 10px; }
[type="text"] { margin: 4px 0; }
[type="text"], select, label > span { display: block; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 70%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<form id='my-form'>
  <input type="text" name='text-values' />
  <input type="text" name='text-values' />
  <input type="text" name='text-values' />
  
  <label>
    <span>red</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected-colors" value="red" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>yellow</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected-colors" value="yellow" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>green</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected-colors" value="green" />
  </label>

  <select name="picked-fruits" multiple>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="text" name='other' value="other value" disabled />

  <input type='submit' name="submit" value="submit" />
  <input type='reset' name="reset" value="reset" />
  <input type='button' name="button" value="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this and revise Answer as needed. Appreciate the alternative option and code sample as well!

Comment: @SourceMatters ... and what does the revision say?

Comment: will try it tonight! got sidetracked with a GET request length issue to a vendor API... lol

Comment: Tested this method tonight. Output looks the same as the first answer's output.  I like it, but I'm not as familiar with some of this syntax (like the "..." or the return formatting). Would be neat if I could combine the "row data" for the criteria into a node for each one, like a key with the rule-criteria-attribute and the values the remainder of the inputs for that row.

Comment: @SourceMatters ... [`...` is spread sytax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It spreads an iterable object like a [form data's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#html) `entries` into an array. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) does achieve the same. And [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the most versatile array method in terms of the results's data structure

Comment: Ah very cool! Will have to read up on those things. In thinking about it more, the current data format it's in actually works well. I think trying to combine each row into its own node might've caused conflicts when duplicate criteria selections are made (could create same key names). On your method, if I wanted to exclude certain field names for example, where would I inject that logic so it's not stored in the final data structure?

Comment: @SourceMatters ... I assume you don't want to exclude certain field-names, but field-names featured by certain form-elements. This is what `FormData` was designed for. Only successful form controls are included into a `FormData` object which is, features a `name` property, is not disabled, is either checked (radio control or checkbox) or has at least one selected option (select element). Thus, one does not need to (re)implement such behavior like you're trying to do. If one does not want the key-value pairs of certain controls be part of the `entries` one should not make them part of the form.

Comment: Great! thanks for that great info. With that info, I removed the "name" property from a "select filter" search input text field. And that allowed it to not be passed as you stated. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `if` statement to convert the existing value into an array if it's not one already. The `if` would look like this:

```js
// Add the value to the object
if (field.name in obj) {
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[field.name])) {
      obj[field.name] = [obj[field.name]];
    }
    obj[field.name].push(field.value);
} else {
    obj[field.name] = field.value;
}
```

Below the working example with the modified code:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myform');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const serialized = form_to_json('myform');
  console.log(serialized);
});

// gather form elements and serialize inputs
    function form_to_json(form_id) {
        console.log(`Getting form with ID ${form_id}`);
        let obj_form = document.getElementById(form_id);

        // Create an object
        var obj = {};
        
        // Loop through each field in the form
        Array.prototype.slice.call(obj_form.elements).forEach(function (field) {
            // Skip some fields we don't need
            if (!field.name || field.disabled || ['file', 'reset', 'submit', 'button'].indexOf(field.type) > -1) return;
            
            // Handle multi-select fields
            if (field.type === 'select-multiple') {
                // Create an array of selected values
                var options = [];
                
                // Loop through the options and add selected ones
                Array.prototype.slice.call(field.options).forEach(function (option) {
                    if (!option.selected) return;
                    options.push(option.value);
                });
                
                // If there are any selection options, add them to the object
                if (options.length) {
                    obj[field.name] = options;
                }
                
                return;
            }
            
            // If it's a checkbox or radio button and it's not checked, skip it
            if (['checkbox', 'radio'].indexOf(field.type) > -1 && !field.checked) return;

            console.log(`${field.name}: ${field.value}`);
            
            // Add the value to the object
            if (field.name in obj) {
                if (!Array.isArray(obj[field.name])) {
                  obj[field.name] = [obj[field.name]];
                }
                obj[field.name].push(field.value);
            } else {
                obj[field.name] = field.value;
            }
        });
        
        // Return the object
        return obj;
    }
```

```html
<form id='myform'>

<input name='crit' />
<input name='crit' />
<input name='crit' />
<input name='otherfied' />

<input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: That makes total sense! Works perfect! Much appreciated!